# Rails not recognizing only one scss file

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

This is the strangest problem I've come across. 
Rails ignores only 1 css file. Which is sessions.css.scss

I created a sessions controller, so ended up with sessions.css.scss file.
There are other scss files in the stylesheets folder. All of them get compiled.

In development as well as production, that one file never gets recognized.
And no, theres absolutely no error in the file, because I was testing only 1 property.
On copy pasting the exact same code into another file, it works.

Oh, and when I rename it to sessions.css, ( no scss ) it works!

How do I find out whats going wrong?

Comment: Can you give us any details on how you're calling the files? Are you using the `@import` directive, or the `require` directives in your application.css file?